# how get a php value inside a self-invoked jquery function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, zend-framework2

I have a page that generates n links in a foreach loop:

```
...some html and php code

<?php foreach ($tables as $table):?>

... some elements generated ...

<td><a  onclick="setPortalId(<?php echo $table['id']?>);$('#fileupload').trigger('click');" class="btn-success btn-sm"><i class="icon-plus white bigger-125"></i>Add / Change</a></td>

... another elements ...

<?php endforeach;?>
```

As you can see, the onclick event in each link execute 2 js functions,the first sets a js var with the php value $table['id'] because i will need this value to determine my zend route and the last function trigges the input fileUpload of the type file:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file"  class="hidden" multiple="" name="files[]">
```

and in the scripts i have this:

```
<script src="/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for    XHR file uploads -->
<script src="/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
<script src="/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS is not required, but included for the responsive demo navigation -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>            

<script>
var idPortal;

function setPortalId(valor) {
    idPortal = valor;
}



/*jslint unparam: true */
/*global window, $ */
$(function () {
 'use strict';
 // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:


var url = '/precos/upload/id/'+ idPortal;
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text(file.name + " adicionado").appendTo('#files');
            window.alert(file.name + " Adicionado.");
        });
    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
    }
}).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
    .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
</script>
```

My question is how I can get the idPortal of the clicked link in the last self-invoqued funtion?Any sugestions?

Answer (score 2):

This is horrible design. You should try to keep your JS as unobtrusive as possible, ie. don't use event handler attributes like `onclick`. Attach the event handler via JS. There are times when this is impractical but I don't see any evidence that that is the case here.

What I would do on the PHP side is to add some classes and a data attribute that I can hook in to from JS:

```
<?php foreach ($tables as $table):?>
    <td>
        <a data-portal-id="<?php echo $table['id']?>" class="btn-success btn-sm btn-upload"><i class="icon-plus white bigger-125"></i>Add / Change</a>
    </td>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Now on the JS side I would simply read the `data-portal-id` from the clicked link, use it to set the URL on the file uploader, and then trigger the click to begin the upload workflow:

```
$(selectorForTheTable).on('click', 'a[data-portal-id].btn-upload', function (e) {
    // pull the portalId from the link's data-portal-id attribute
    var portalId = $(this).data('portalId'),
        $uploader = $('#fileupload');
         
    // set the url for the upload based on out portalId
    $uploader.fileupload('option', 'url', '/precos/upload/id/'+ portalId);
    
    // invoke the click
    $('#fileupload').trigger('click');
});
```

The one thing missing here is that you might want to set something up so that when the uploader is closed or all the uploads complete the URL is set back to null or a URL of no consequence. This would help to ensure something going wrong on the client can't mistakenly upload files to the wrong endpoint.

[Here is an example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myaLzhm4/) that works as much as a Fiddle can :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your url global and update it later in that context. Use it like

```
var idPortal;
var url;

function setPortalId(valor) {
   idPortal = valor;
   url = '/precos/upload/id/'+ idPortal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach to seperate PHP (serverside **business logic**) and Javascript (**non-business critical GUI enhencement**), is to put all variables from PHP into the DOM and then later work with it:

```
<script>
var phpValues = <?php echo json_encode($yourPhpValuesArrayOrObject); ?>;
</script>

....

<script>
```

The attributes connected with business data from inside the HTML (=**semantic structure**) should go with a `data-*` attribute as already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `url` when the page is first loaded, not after the user clicks on the link. Add that to the `setPortalId` function:

```
function setPortalId(valor) {
    idPortal = valor;
    url = '/precos/upload/id/'+ idPortal;
}
```

Comment: I Did your sugestion rigth now,but the value is still undefined:

POST http://sandbox/precos/upload/id/undefined 200 OK 48ms

Answer (score 0):

thank you everyone,but I used another approach to get the correct value of the clicked element.like was said,the function is self-invoked in the page loading,so in this moment the global var still null.I as using the blueimp jquery file upload,so reading the documentation I saw that is possible send another values during the ajax request just adding news inputs in the form.with this I solved my problem.